# My apache doesn't show up Syntax error using php

Tags: php, apache, lamp

i am using LAMP on my server and when i make a syntax error on a `php` my `apached` doesn't show it, it just shows a blank white page,
How can i configure it and make it displays the error ?

Comment: Follow http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: Displaying errors on a live/production system is considered bad practice - it can expose a lot of information about the internals of your application. Further relying on display of errors in your browser will add complications to debugging of issues when PHP is generating different content types (CSS, images, Javascript, audio, downloadable content....). Make sure that the errors are being LOGGED and ensure you are checking the logs regularly.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);